# How to represent an ID in model/dao interfaces

Tags: java, hibernate, mongodb

I'm currently refactoring some model and DAO classes in a legacy system and would like to test performance for persistence using MongoDB and various relational database options. I'm struggling with the best way to represent the ID in the interface. I have the following package structure

```
mypackage.model.Model
mypackage.model.mongo.MongoModel
mypackage.model.mysql.MySQLModel
```

The Model interface would look like this

```
public interface Model {
    public String getValue();
    public void setValue (String value);
}
```

And the MongoModel (using morphia in this case) would look like this

```
import mypackage.model.Model
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Id;
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Property;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

@Entity(value="collectionname")
public class MongoModel implements Model {
    @Id private ObjectId id;
    @Property("value") String value;

    public ObjectId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(ObjectId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

The MySQLModel (using hibernate in this case) would look like this

```
import mypackage.model.Model
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="tablename")
public class MySQLModel implements Model {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    @Column(name="value") private String value;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Since the datatype for an ID is potentially different (in this case a Long vs. ObjectId), how can I represent the ID in the Model interface?

The same issue applies to my DAOs.

```
mypackage.dao/ModelDAO
mypackage.dao.mongo.MongoModelDAO
mypackage.dao.mysql.MySQLModelDAO
```

I've considered adding an upcast reference to the ID as follows

```
public interface Model {
    public Object getId ();
    public void setId (Object id);
    public String getValue ();
    public void setValue (String value);
}
```

I could then create an InvalidKeyFormat exception and throw that in the case of a bad ID being provided. However, this lacks compile time checking of the ID type.

I could also build a key generation mechanism and normalize the key values between datastore technologies, but there are benefits to using the ObjectId format which is default for MongoDB.

Is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

use a GUID for both classes and make the Id readonly so the database at hand can generate it on saving. for the Mongomodel you will need to convert the GUID to ObjectId back and forth in the property getter/setter, in the case of MongoDb just padd the bytes of the ObjectId to create the GUID and remove the padding when used in repositories

```
public interface Model
{
    public Guid getId ();
    public String getValue ();
    public void setValue (String value);
}
```

Comment: This would fit within the "key generation mechanism" that I mentioned and a Guid should help ensure unique values. However, in a relational database searching on a Guid value would be slower than the typical integer value. A similar slowdown could result in MongoDB depending on how the value is stored.

Comment: for sql you could use GUIDComb (NHibernate has, hibernate should too?) which playes nive with PK index. For Mongo ObjectId is the prefered id and i suspect it will be fast enough.